# ImportError: Using `low_cpu_mem_usage=True` or a `device_map` requires Accelerate: `pip install accelerate`

Tags: huggingface-transformers, amazon-sagemaker-studio, accelerate

Using HuggingFace Transformer I am trying to create a pipeline, by running below code (code is running on a SageMaker Jupyter Lab):

```
pipeline = transformers.pipeline(
    "text-generation",
    model="meta-llama/Llama-2-7b-chat-hf",
    torch_dtype=torch.float16,
    device_map="auto",
)
```

However, it generates following error:

```
ImportError: Using `low_cpu_mem_usage=True` or a `device_map` requires Accelerate: `pip install accelerate`
```

Reference:

```
Packages version:print(accelerate.__version__), print(transformers.__version__)
0.21.0
4.31.0
```

Answer (score 32):

I found the root cause of issue. After installed the accelarate package, we must restart the notebook kernel. That solved the problem.

Comment: This is worked for "Falcom LLMs", thank you very much

Comment: Correct. Worked for Falcon LLM

Answer (score 2):

in colab, I got same issue

```
!pip install -Uqqq


!pip -qqq install bitsandbytes accelerate
```

running above cell solved issue for me.
No need to restart kernal.

Answer (score 2):

Error mentions (Also few solutions mention) about installing *accelerate* and then, restarting jupyter kernel. If these two steps don't work.. **install *accelerate* with following command**:

```
pip install git+https://github.com/huggingface/accelerate
```

and **then restart the kernel**. It will install the latest accelerate version.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using google colab than load your model in 4 bit quantization its worked for me

```
quantization_config = BitsAndBytesConfig(
    load_in_4bit=True,
    bnb_4bit_compute_dtype=torch.float16,
    bnb_4bit_quant_type="nf4",
    bnb_4bit_use_double_quant=True,
)

model_4bit=AutoModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained(
model_id,device_map="auto",quantization_config=quantization_config
)
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution is to change from:

pipe = StableDiffusionPipeline.from_pretrained(model_id, torch_dtype=torch.float16)

to:

pipe = StableDiffusionPipeline.from_pretrained(model_id, torch_dtype=torch.float16, **low_cpu_mem_usage=False**)